# Gitlab Tags API 404

Tags: tags, composer-php, gitlab

why this URL shows 404 not found

https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/bahram.davodi%2Fbankmellat-magento2/repository/tags

Im trying to use VCS repository in my composer file then it shows 404
[image]

Comment: fixed ... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by remove that  ->>> . <<<-  form gitlab username :))

then https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/bahram.davodi%2Fbankmellat-magento2/repository/tags changes to :
https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/bahramdavodi%2Fbankmellat-magento2/repository/tags

fixed